# How switch between 2 css files (arabic and english css files) in Vue3 js?

Tags: vue.js

I have created my project with vue-cli and I have loaded css files using import in my main.js file.

I need to load different css files if user decides to see website in RTL or LTR languages

when user want to see web site in RTL I want load css-RTL.css only in main.js and remove css-LTR.css
And vise versa.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find another solution which I have one css file and inside it class arabic and class english,
when user swtich language I update app id with current class language,

Thanks.